# Load Rcpp module

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have an Studio Rcpp project. One on my file contains the following declarations:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


int square(int x)
{
  return x*x;
}

RCPP_MODULE(mod_bar) {
  function( "sqaure", &square );
}
```

I am trying to use the `square` function by using R after the my library is loaded:

```
library(myLib)
require(Rcpp)
Module(mod_bar)
```

But I get the following error message:

> Uninitialized module named "mod_bar" from package ".GlobalEnv"

Answer (score 1):

Take an existing package with Rcpp Modules and compare.

Maybe you just need a `loadModules("mod_bar")`, maybe you need something else.  We can't tell from here.

*Every* full regression test for Rcpp includes building and the embedded [testRcppModule](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/tree/master/inst/unitTests/testRcppModule) package containing a module.  I would start to compare to this one.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are missing // [[Rcpp::export]] before declaration of your function.